# How to set jsf locale in junit test?

Tags: jsf, junit, mocking, mockito, jsf-2.2

i have a junit test method that calls a backing bean method as follows:

```
myBackingBean.signup();
```

, in the backing bean method there's a call to `Faces.getLocale()` and it gives null pointer exception in the line

```
UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
```

please advise how to be able to set locale in test method and fix this error.

Comment: You should probably mock the `Faces.getLocale()` method. Are you using a mock library? If yes, which one? If not, how are you configuring the collaborators in the tests?

Comment: @elias, i am using mockito and powermock, please advise how can i mock Faces.getLocale() properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution was as follows:

**1- add the following class to project:**

```
public abstract class FacesContextMocker extends FacesContext {
    private FacesContextMocker() {
    }

    private static final Release RELEASE = new Release();

    private static class Release implements Answer<Void> {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            setCurrentInstance(null);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static FacesContext mockFacesContext() {
        FacesContext context = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
        setCurrentInstance(context);
        Mockito.doAnswer(RELEASE).when(context).release();
        return context;
    }
}
```

**2- In @Before for the test use the following code:**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContextMocker.mockFacesContext();
    UIViewRoot uiViewRoot = Mockito.mock(UIViewRoot.class);
    Mockito.when(facesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot())
            .thenReturn(uiViewRoot);
    Mockito.when(
            facesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale())
            .thenReturn(new Locale("en"));
```